# "transform apply" - using tuple elements as parameters to one function to construct a parameter pack for another

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Given the following:

```
constexpr auto t = std::make_tuple(3, 2, 1);
template<auto x>
auto InnerF() {return -x;}

auto OuterF(auto... args) {return (args + ...);}
```

I can use the elements of t as parameters to InnerF directly:

```
InnerF<std::get<0>(t)>();
```

But I want to be able to write

```
std::apply([](auto... arg) { return OuterF(InnerF<arg>()...); }, t);
```

But this does not work, I get

```
<source>:29:44: error: no matching function for call to 'InnerF'
std::apply([](auto... arg) { return OuterF(InnerF<arg>()...) ;}, t);
.
.
.
<source>:29:44: error: no matching function for call to 'InnerF'
std::apply([](auto... arg) { return OuterF(InnerF<arg>()...) ;}, t);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'x'
auto InnerF() {return -x;}
```

I don't understand why the arg is considered invalid, I tried modifying the syntax a number of ways and reimplementing apply myself, but couldn't crack it -
is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `InnerF` is expecting a non-type template parameter. Those must be compile-time constants, which `auto... arg` are not. Using gcc 12.1, I get this more helpful error message:

```
<source>:10:59: error: no matching function for call to 'InnerF<arg#0>()'
   10 |     std::apply([](auto... arg) { return OuterF(InnerF<arg>()...); }, t);
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:4:6: note: candidate: 'template<auto x> auto InnerF()'
    4 | auto InnerF() {return -x;}
      |      ^~~~~~
<source>:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:10:59: error: 'arg#0' is not a constant expression
   10 |     std::apply([](auto... arg) { return OuterF(InnerF<arg>()...); }, t);
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:10:59: note: in template argument for type 'int'
```

The solution is to write `InnerF` like so:

```
auto InnerF(auto x) { return -x; }
```

And call `std::apply` like this:

```
std::apply([](auto... arg) { return OuterF(InnerF(arg)...); }, t);
```

Comment: I see, thanks! But would that actually cause InnerF to be evaluated at runtime?
Since I know t at compile-time, I would like InnerF to be evaluated at compile-time as well.

Comment: @xamvolagis You can make both functions `constexpr`, then write e.g. `constexpr auto negative_sum = std::apply(...)`.